# React Search Filter of Objects not filtering

Tags: filter, react-redux

I'm trying to create a search filter that will filter through facility names that lives in an array of objects.If I hard code an array into the state the filter works, but I need it to drab the info from props. The filtered list is being generated and showing all of the names on the screen but when I type it the textbox to filter nothing happens. What have I overlooked?

```
class FacilitySearch extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        search: ""
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(actions.getFacilitiesList());
}

//The subsr limits the # of characters a user can enter into the seach box
updateSearch = event => {
    this.setState({ search: event.target.value.substr(0, 10) });
};

render() {
    if (!this.props.facilityList) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    let filteredList = this.props.facilityList;
    filteredList.filter(facility => {
        return facility.facilityName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.search}
                onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}
                placeholder="Enter Text Here..."
            />
            <ul>
                {filteredList.map(facility => {
                    return <li key={facility.generalIdPk}>{facility.facilityName}</li>;
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
facilityList: state.facilityList.facilityList
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FacilitySearch)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not storing the return value of filter in any variable.

You should do something like:

```
let filteredList = this.props.facilityList.filter(facility => {
        return facility.facilityName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):
The filter() method **creates a new array** with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Comment: Thank you - I didn't think that separating this.props.facilityList into a variable first would have made a difference, apparently it does!

Comment: Yes! It’s a common pattern among functions like **map** , **filter** and **reduce** . Glad to help!